# Division in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I am trying to use division in SQL Server. I have tried the code snippet below.

```
    SELECT m.[Profit] / f.[Target]
```

And I have also tried

```
    SELECT SUM(m.[Profit] / f.[Target])
```

but I get the error

> Divide by zero error encountered.
>   Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

What is the reason for this and how can I fix it? Suggested fixes online say that this code should work but it doesn't.

Thanks

Comment: The reason is that one of the values for `f.[Target]` is 0.  You can fix it by telling SQL-Server what you want to do in those cases.

Comment: Depending on the datatypes of Profit and target, you could get caught by integer math as well. As long as one of them is not an integer you should be ok though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NULLIF` to avoid divided by zero exception

```
SELECT SUM(m.[Profit] / NULLIF(f.[Target],0))
```

When denominator is zero then it will be replaced with `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

If I were trying to determine the % of a goal (inferred by profit /target columns), I would try something like:

```
  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(f.[Target],0) = 0 THEN  NULL -- or whatever you need to return when the target value is undefined, or it is 0
    ELSE  m.[Profit] / f.[Target] END AS [result]
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you get specifies exactly what is the problem. Your code is trying to divide by zero, which is mathematically impossible.

Please NULLIF to avoid this error.